# Adding multiple tables to plotly plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Im trying my best to figure out a way of plotting two tables on the same plotly subplots but cant seem to get past this part. Searching has has not been fruitful.

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 2, cols=1, subplot_titles=('Continious 

Features','Catagorical Features'))

cont_table = FF.create_table(cont_data_matrix, index= True,index_title='Feature')
cat_table = FF.create_table(cont_data_matrix, index= True,index_title='Feature')

cont_table['figure'].extend()

fig.append_trace(cont_table, 1,1)
fig.append_trace(cont_table, 2,1)

py.plot(fig)
```

Comment: I know this the same table twice I just havent culled the data for the second yet.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the `cufflinks` library which ties together `pandas` and `plotly`, giving `pandas` dataframes the `iplot()` command. https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/

```
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd

table.iplot(kind='scatter', subplots=True, shape=(2,1), filename='cufflinks_test')
```

So now the trick is to get the `table` set up. You want the data for each trace to be in different columns, and the index to correspond to the X values. `pivot_table()` is extremely useful for getting your data into the right shape.

If you include some dummy data for `cont_table` and `cat_table` I could provide code to combine them so that the above code works.